# Test zoom levels of page on browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

To zoom in webpage on browser I searched solution and used two ways but on both I am receiving an error can someone please help me identify where is the mistake or whats wrong with the code. Browser I am using is **Chrome**

First method:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD));
```

Error received on this: 
   **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element**

To solve above error I tried:

```
 element = driver.findElement(By.tagname("html"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD);
        actions.build().perform();
```

Error received: **unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.**

Also I tried to replace element "html" with "body" but zoom not worked

Comment: You should use Javascript Executor to perform this action. See Raja Sekhar's answer.

Comment: Suggested answer isn't working for me. No zooming effect can be seen

Comment: @bad_deadpool can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [v̲e̲r̲s̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲3̲.̲3̲.̲1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/selenium-java-3.3.1.zip) of the Selenium Java Client Driver and [C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲2̲.̲2̲8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/), the following works (where the number in single quotes represents the zoom level to use; 1 = 100%, 1.5 = 150%, etc.):

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '1.5'");
```

---

In addition, the zoom level in Firefox can be modified with the following:
1. The aforementioned Java Client Driver
2. [G̲e̲c̲k̲o̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲v̲0̲.̲1̲5̲.̲0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.15.0)
3. These classes:
**java.awt.Robot**
**java.awt.event.KeyEvent**

First of all, instantiate the Robot class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

This code causes the zoom level to *decrease*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
```

This code causes the zoom level to *increase*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
```

Comment: This definitely works for chrome. Is there any way for firefox?

Comment: @RabiaAsif Yes. I added a Firefox solution to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

it should work (work around)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
```

Comment: This isn't working

Comment: hi, this is javascript based it should work most probably,
if still not working... once check whether or not you initiated the javascriptExecutor properly, hope this can help you, and please try @User253489's answer below as well  cheers.

Comment: answer by User253489 works for me on chrome only. How to make that work for firefox?